# Permutations of n elements into r groups Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I don't know how to create an algorithm / which to use for the following problem:

If I have a set of 20 elements (e.g. A -> T) and have a string of length 8, what are the permutations I could make? (I know there's around 390 million)

e.g. we could have ABCDEFGH or EFHGATRI.

Does anyone have any ideas to help me?

Comment: Have you checked [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Comment: Are you thinking of combinations (where the order doesn't matter) ? There are 5,079,110,400 permutations of 8 in 20 but only 125,970 combinations of 8 in 20.  Processing 5 billion permutations will take quite a while but combinations could be processed in a reasonable time.

Comment: If you are searching for permutations (or combinations) that meet a set of criteria, generating all possibilities and filtering them will generally take too long.  You would typically need to merge the combination generation logic and the filtering criteria in order to short-circuit the generation process.  Please add you actual objective for these permutations to you question so we can provide useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has specific function for your issue [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.

So, you can use it for your task

```
["".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations("abcd", 3)]
```

```
> ['abc', 'abd', 'acb', 'acd', 'adb', 'adc', 'bac', 'bad', 'bca', 'bcd', 'bda', 'bdc', 'cab', 'cad', 'cba', 'cbd', 'cda', 'cdb', 'dab', 'dac', 'dba', 'dbc', 'dca', 'dcb']
```

Also, you can use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to reduce RAM usage

```
def perms():
    for perm in itertools.permutations("abcdefghij", 5):
        yield "".join(perm)

for p in perms():
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all permutations, given the number of possibilities, better keep it as a generator. For this, use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
from string import ascii_uppercase

letters = ascii_uppercase[:20]

perms = map(''.join, permutations(letters, r=8))  # this doesn't generate
                                                  # anything yet

# then use it lazily

for p in perms:
    # do something


# or get elements one by one
next(perm)
```

If you only want random possibilities, use `random.sample`:

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_uppercase

''.join(sample(ascii_uppercase[:20], 8))
```

example output: `'IKEDQRTS'`

Comment: Or `''.join(random.sample(ascii_uppercase[:20], 8))`

Comment: Yes, that's actually better ;)